# Convolution of $L^2$ functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, compactness, convolution

Let $u\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$: then $u\ast u$ is a bounded continuous function. Let me assume now that $u\ast u$ is compactly supported. Is there anything relevant that could be said on the support of $u$, in particular in the case where $n\ge 2$?

Comment: Do you know what happens for $n=1$?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Assuming that $u$ is even and real-valued, you get that the Fourier transform of $u\ast u$ is even and non-negative. Now an analytic non-negative function of one variable is a sum of squares, something which is not true in higher dimensions. Now, in one dimension you can write $u\ast u$ as a finite sum of $u_j\ast u_j$ where each $u_j$ is compactly supported; some details need to be completed, but there is clearly no hope to get something of that type in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 8):

$u$ need not be compactly supported.

Take any $\varphi\in C_0^{\infty}$, $\varphi\not\equiv 0$, and let $\widehat{u}=\widehat{\varphi}^{1/2}$ be any non-holomorphic (but measurable) square root. (Typically, $\widehat{u}$ will fail to be holomorphic automatically, when $\widehat{\varphi}$ has zeros.) Clearly $\widehat{u}\in L^2$, since $\widehat{\varphi}$ is a Schwartz function.

Then $(u*u)\widehat{\:\:\:}=\widehat{u}\,^2=\widehat{\varphi}$, so $u*u=\varphi$ is compactly supported, but $u$ isn't because its Fourier transform is not entire.

We can also produce explicit examples in this fashion, if we start out with a (non-smooth) $\varphi$ whose Fourier transform we can compute. For example, $u(x)=\log |(x-1)/(x+1)|$ works; this comes from a triangular $\varphi$.

Comment: A similar counteraxample holds in the periodic case. $1+\cos t$ is a trigonometric polynomial but its square root is not and has infinitely many non zero Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Not understood the explicit example. The FT of triangular function is not the $u$ you wrote.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I start out with the triangular function, take its FT (=Dirichlet kernel squared), then the non-holomorphic square root described above of that, and finally the inverse FT. Or, equivalently, the Hilbert transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: You can also just check using the FT of $\log |x|$ (see any table) that the $u$ I gave works.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for your answer. It seems that in one dimension, it is possible to find an holomorphic square root, for instance if you know that $u\ast u$ is even real-valued with a non-negative Fourier transform. However, in more than one dimension, I guess that even with the more stringent assumption above, it is not possible to find an holomorphic square root.

Answer (score 5):

In one dimension, observe from inspection of the Fourier symbol of the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) $H$ that one has the identity $Hu * Hu = - u*u$ for any $u \in L^2$.  So one can easily generate a non-compactly supported $u \in L^2({\bf R})$ for which $u*u$ is compactly supported by starting with any bump function of non-zero mean and applying the Hilbert transform to get a function that decays like $1/x$ at infinity.

More generally, in higher dimensions we have $T_m u * T_m u = u * u$ whenever $T_m$ is a Fourier multiplier whose symbol $m$ takes values in $\{-1,+1\}$.  By taking a highly discontinuous choice for $m$ and applying $T_m$ to a bump function one can create $u \in L^2$ that decay extremely slowly at infinity (in fact I think any decay consistent with square-integrability could be permitted, though I have not checked this carefully) but for which $u*u$ remains compactly supported (and even smooth).

Answer (score 3):

$\renewcommand\C{\mathbb C}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$To complement the [answer by Christian Remling](https://mathoverflow.net/a/447181/36721), let us provide explicit examples of $u\in L^2(\R^n)$ such that $u*u$ is compactly supported but $u$ is not compactly supported.

Consider first the case $n=1$. Let $w(x):=\frac12\,1(|x|<1)$ for real $x$. Then $w\in L^2(\R)$ and for the Fourier transform $\hat w$ of $w$ and all real $t\ne0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \hat w(t)=\int_\R dx\, e^{itx} w(x)=\frac{\sin t}t, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
with $\hat w(0)=1$. Let now $v:=w*w$. Then $v$ is of course compactly supported, and
\begin{equation*}
    \hat v=\hat w^2. 
\end{equation*}
Next, let $u$ be the inverse Fourier transform of $|\hat w|=\sqrt{\hat v}$, so that $u$ is the limit in $L^2(\R)$ as $A\to\infty$ of the functions $u_A$ defined by the formula
\begin{equation*}
    u_A(x):=\frac1{2\pi}\,\int_{-A}^A dx e^{-itx} \frac{|\sin t|}{|t|}
    =\frac1{2\pi}\,\int_{-A}^A dx \cos tx\, \frac{|\sin t|}{|t|}  
\end{equation*}
for real $x$.
Note that $u\in L^2(\R)$, since $\hat u=|\hat w|\in L^2(\R)$. (One may also note that the function $u$ is real-valued.)

Also, $u*u=v$, since $\hat u^2=|\hat w|^2=\hat v$. So, $u*u$ is compactly supported.

If the function $u$ were compactly supported, then, by the easy part of [Schwartz's Paley–Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz%27s_Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), the Fourier transform $\hat u=|\hat w|$ could be extended to an entire function -- which is impossible, because, in view of \eqref{1}, the function $|\hat w|$ is not smooth on $\R$.

Thus, $w\in L^2(\R)$ and $u*u$ is compactly supported, but $u$ is not compactly supported. (In fact, $u$ is not even in $L^1(\R)$ -- because then $\hat u=|\hat w|$ would be differentiable, which it is clearly not.)

---

To get now, for any natural $n$, an explicit example of a function $U\in L^2(\R^n)$ such that $U*U$ is compactly supported but $U$ is not compactly supported, it is enough to tensorize the function $u$ from the "one-dimensional" example above:
\begin{equation*}
    U(x):=u^{\otimes n}(x)=u(x_1)\cdots u(x_n)
\end{equation*}
for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\R^n$.

Comment: But $\widehat{u}=\widehat{v}^{1/2}$ will not be entire if $\widehat{v}$ has zeros, so the Paley-Wiener theorem doesn't apply to $u$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Good point.